# Передача параметров слотов в компонент

Tags: vue.js

В руководстве по Vue есть пример.
[Деструктурирование входных параметров слота](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)

```
<current-user v-slot="{ user }">
  {{ user.firstName }}
</current-user>
```

Дополняю его компонентом.

```
<current-user v-slot="{ user }">
  {{ user.firstName }}
  <component :val="user" :is="component"/>
</current-user>
```

Возникает ошибка:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick:
>   "InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':
>   ',' is not a valid attribute name."

Что я делаю не так, не подскажете?

Comment: что означает `component` в этой строчке `:is="component"`? Откуда это значение?

Comment: component работает, просто код опустил. Немного поэкспериментировав, выяснил, что если перейти к варианту <component v-model="user" :is="component"/>, то ошибка не происходит.

Comment: сделай [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть ошибку

Comment: извините, это было достаточно давно и код уже переделан без использования слотов. А по данному вопросу, то вроде все понятно, раз вью где-то внутри реализации использует "execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element'", то привязка аттрибута "user" должна быть двусторонней.